# segue transition with condition storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I am new to storyboard and xcode (using 4.4)

I would like to implement a login condition, that if accomplished - the segue would work. Otherwise, the user should stay on the same view.

I created 2 UIView: ViewController and Bar Controller.

I also created a segue from ViewController to Bar Controller and set its identifier to loginSegue as modal.

In LoginViewController.m I added the following:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    self.email = self.emailText.text;
    self.password = self.passwordText.text;
   if ([self.email isEqualToString:@"O"] && [self.password isEqualToString:@"O"])
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender];
    else
        [passwordText setText:@""];   
}
```

When I debug the code - I see that the if skips to else in case of email and password that to not equal to O, however the segue (transition to the new view) still happens.

How can I prevent the user to be transferred to the new view?

BTW, if I remove the if else condition - the user is being transferred to the next view automatically. It seems to me that it was configured somewhere when I drew the segue from one view to the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the blank line in between your `if` and `[self perform...]`

Additionally, you may want to consider keeping your `if-else` statements in braces to keep this problem from happening again:

```
if ([self.email isEqualToString:@"O"] && [self.password isEqualToString:@"O"]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender];
}else{
    [passwordText setText:@""];
}
```

If this doesn't solve the problem then be sure to varify that the segue is attached to the two controllers and not directly to a button.

Comment: In my code I don't have blank lines - it was copied like this (not sure why. I changed it). anyways - adding the brackets does not help

Comment: @Odelya Is this segue connected directly to this button in interface builder?

Comment: in the storyboard, the segue is connected from the ViewController (login view) to the Tab Controller. I did it with right click on the orange icon login view controller and drawing the line to the tab bar controller and assigning the identifier

Comment: @Odelya So you linked the segue directly between the controllers and it is not directly linked to a button correct?

Comment: Sorry - you were right. It was connected from the button. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can change your answer - since the provided answer is incorrect - only the comments

Comment: @Odelya No problem, and thanks for the up vote! and I changed the answer.